# Issue with understanding Side Channel Attacks

Tags: side-channel-attack, dpa

I am currently working on Side Channel Attacks (SCA) on Kyber and Dilithium. I have found myself quite confused with side channel, because so much is mentionned all the time.

For instance, I don't understand when to use distinguishers, when to use tools like the t-test, when you need to work with key guesses, etc... In the articles I am reading, they sometimes describe the attacks, which I understand, but they don't talk about which tool, which analysis you need, and this really confuses me. I guess I understand each concept individually (DPA, CPA, t-test), but I struggle to put it together.

So if anyone has an idea on where to start, a link to explainations, that would be great.

Comment: You can take a look at the book "Power Analysis Attacks" by Mangard, Oswald and Popp for an introduction. For the various methods you should always have in mind, what your goal is. If you "just" want to know/evaluate if an implementation might be vulnerable to side-channel attacks, you use other methods (like t-test) than if you actually want to break it (with DPA/CPA).